# Unclear about Jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I know this is a basic knowledge about Jquery but I couldn't find anywhere to search and solve this problem. In my project I have a form and I'm using jquery to reset every input in that form but I couldn't use reset() method like in javascript. I searched and found that in Jquery if I want to reset a form with reset() function, I need to use this *$('#form')**[0]***. I just really want to know what does it mean when using **[0]**. Thank you very much. 
EX:

```
$(function() {
 $('#reset').click(function() {
   $('#form')[0].reset();
 });
})
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: `$('#form')` is nothing but JQuery object for that form whereas `$('#form')[0]` is nothing but native DOM element on which you can execute native DOM manipulation functions

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: jQuery does not have a reset function for forms, so your syntax grabs the native DOM and uses its reset

Comment: if I remember correctly, the first reference to every jquery object is the native javascript implementation itself. 
So when you are using `var obj = $obj[0];`
you are actually doing the reverse of `var $obj = $(obj);`

It's like you are "de-encapsulating" a jquery object.

Comment: You can use code below;

    $("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); 
    $("select").find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);

if you need specify specific form, you should add form's id in the beginning of the selectors

    $("#myform select")..

Comment: JQuery object usually contain an array of DOM elements. Even, if it's just one element (when you selecting by id), it's still an array with one element within. So, **[0]** is refernce to the first element in this array.

Comment: Oh! My bad because of my lack of jquery basic. Now I know it returns an array. Thank guys!

Comment: @VladimirLiubimov Thanks, Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The [0] means that $() is returning and array of elements and you are getting the first one. So you are getting the the form DOM element.

Comment: So that even if I select with an ID of an element by jquery, it still return an array, right?

Comment: No, jquery should only return an array when using a class selector. Have a look at what is actually hold in your console.log($("#form")[0])

Comment: It is actually retrieving your inputs fields. The ones within the form

Comment: @kimy82 From documentation: [link](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). "Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a **collection** of either zero or one DOM element." So, even for id selector it's return a collection. It's may be confusing at first sight, but it's just unification of interface.

Comment: @HuyLe To be clear, it's not an array. All JQuery methods return a JQuery object, that implements indexer "[]" operation. It makes that object an array-like. Another example of such object is "arguments" object  [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: @VladimirLiubimov Thank you! I got it! :)